# Wordpress 4.3 multisite image generate and resize issue

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

When I upload an image into the media library on a sub-site in our **WordPress Multisite** only the original image is uploaded. The smaller images could not be uploaded.

I have done the following:

- Map and file rights to 777, would not solve the problem
- Imagic is installed on the server (version 3.1.2)
- GD Library also installed (version 2.6.0)

Thanks a lot for your help!